# Segmentation fault when using a tridimensional dynamic matrix

Tags: c, dynamic, matrix, segmentation-fault, malloc

So I have this function:

```
int***    loadmatrix(FILE *pimage,int height,int width) {
int ***matrix;
int control,control2,control3;

matrix=(int***)malloc(height*sizeof(int));
for (control=0; control<height; control++) {
    matrix[control]=(int**)malloc(width*sizeof(int));
}
for (control=0; control<height; control++) {
    for (control2=0; control2<width; control2++) {
        matrix[control][control2]=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    }
}

fseek(pimage,54,SEEK_SET); 
for(control=0; control<height; control++) {
    for(control2=0; control2<width; control2++) {
        for(control3=0; control3<3; control3++) {
            matriz[control][control2][control3]=fgetc(pimage);
            fseek(pimage,1,SEEK_CUR);
        }
        fseek(pimage,1,SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
return matrix;
```

}

It recieves a FILE pointer to a .BMP image file, the image's height and width, and attempts to create a dynamic tridimensional matrix to store the RGB values of each pixel (Ignoring the Alpha one, wich is always '0' in .BMPs). It always ends up with a segmentation fault unless I comment out the first control variable when filling it and replace it with 0 (so instead of 'matrix[control][control2][control3]' its 'matrix[0][control2][control3]').

Any ideas?

Comment: `height*sizeof(int**)`, `width*sizeof(int*)`

Comment: and **do not** cast the return value of `malloc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that `sizeof(<pointer>) == sizeof(int)`. This is not always true, especially on 64-bit platforms. That's why you should allocate with calls like `matrix=malloc(height*sizeof(int**));` instead of what you have. I guess checking retval of `fseek()` and `malloc()` would also help - at least put assert() so you'll know it works.